# Add months in db date using interval in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, intervals

I want to add month in transaction date using mysql interval function by join plan table and transaction table,however this method not working but If I add months in static way to transaction date it is working.

`plan` table:

```
plan_id    plan
1         6 month    
2         12 month    
3         3 month
```

`transaction` table:

```
id  user_id  subscribed_on   plan_id    
1     2       2020-04-04     1    
2     4       2019-02-22     2
```

Mysql  query (not working):

```
SELECT t.* FROM transaction t inner join plan p on p.plan_id=t.plan_id 
where t.user_id=2 and DATE_ADD(date(t.subscribed_on), INTERVAL p.plan) >= CURDATE() 
order by t.id desc
```

If I add month in static way  than it is working fine:

```
SELECT t.* FROM transaction t inner join plan p on p.plan_id=t.plan_id 
where t.user_id=2 and DATE_ADD(date(t.subscribed_on),
INTERVAL 6 month) >= CURDATE() 
order by t.id desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not support using interval that way. Unlike in other databaes (such as Postgres for example), the unit argument is a keyword, not a literal string.

I would suspect that your table may store other intervals than just months (say, years, days, and so on). If so, you can use string functions and a `case` expression to accommodate the different possible values, like:

```
select t.* 
from transaction t 
inner join plan p on p.plan_id = t.plan_id 
where 
    t.user_id = 2 
    and date(t.subscribed_on) + case substring_index(p.plan, ' ', -1)
        when 'year'  then interval substring_index(p.plan, ' ', 1) year
        when 'month' then interval substring_index(p.plan, ' ', 1) month
        when 'day'   then interval substring_index(p.plan, ' ', 1) day
    end
    >= current_date
order by t.id desc
```

The logic here is to split the stored interval string into two parts: the number, and the unit; the `case` expression processes the unit and generate the proper literal interval accordingly.

Comment: here You are mentioning manually writing case month year day I am joining plan table it can be month or year, can you show me by joining query.

Comment: @msp: yes. This is what the query in my answer does.

Comment: I am unable to understand what to do bcoz, year month day is passing static way how i it going to work?

Comment: @msp: the `case` expression looks at what is inside the table, and generates the correct interval accordingly. Give the query a try!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately a string in the data is not equivalent to an interval.  One method is:

```
date(t.subscribed_on) + interval substring_index(plan, ' ') + 0 month
```

Note here that `month` is a keyword, not a string.

Comment: can't I use 6 months or 12 months?

Comment: @msp . . . This extracts the number from the `plan` column.  I'm not sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try to force the `plan` column in the `plan` table to be an integer. Does not seem to be possible to cast a string to an interval.

I tried like so:

```
WITH
plan( plan_id,plan) AS (
          SELECT 1,'6 month'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'12 month'    
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'3 month'
)
,
transaction(id,user_id,subscribed_on,plan_id) AS (
          SELECT 1,2,DATE '2020-09-04',1    
UNION ALL SELECT 2,4,DATE '2019-02-22',2 
)
SELECT t.*
FROM transaction t
INNER JOIN plan p ON p.plan_id = t.plan_id
WHERE t.user_id = 2
  AND DATE_ADD(
        DATE(t.subscribed_on)
      , INTERVAL CAST(REPLACE(plan,' month','') AS SIGNED) MONTH
    ) >= CURDATE()
ORDER BY t.id DESC
```

(returns no results, as you don't have any dates high enough in your example data...)